# Calculating Max with commons library

Tags: java, apache-commons

I use commons.math3 for calculating some statistical moments, like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.*;
```

And in my code:

```
    double beatsdifa[] = new double[beatsdif.size()];
    //fill array
    query.add(""+ percentile.evaluate(beatsdifa, 80.0));
    GeometricMean geoMean = new GeometricMean();
    query.add("" + geoMean.evaluate(beatsdifa));
    Mean mean2 = new Mean();
    query.add("" + mean2.evaluate(beatsdifa));
    Variance variance = new Variance();
    query.add("" + variance.evaluate(beatsdifa));
    StandardDeviation stdDev = new StandardDeviation();
    query.add(""+stdDev.evaluate(beatsdifa));
    Skewness skewness = new Skewness();
    query.add(""+skewness.evaluate(beatsdifa));
    Kurtosis kurtosis = new Kurtosis();
    query.add(""+kurtosis.evaluate(beatsdifa));
```

Now I also want to calculate Max, Min and Range.

I tried it like this, but that gives me an error:

```
        Min mix = new Min();
        query.add("" + min.evaluate(beatsdifa));
        Max max = new Max();
        query.add("" + max.evaluate(beatsdifa));
```

"The method double[] is undefined for max.evaluate."

Sorry to ask this perhaps easy questions, but the commons documentation was not so clear and I did not see an easy way to calculate this. 
Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commons library provides to classes named `Max` and `Min`. Make sure, that you import the correct one, which is

```
org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.rank.Max
```

The other one is

```
org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Max
```

Comment: Oh great! I had this one import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Max;